# How to edit CSS style of a div using C# in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, css

I'm trying to grab a div's ID in the code behind (C#) and set some css on it.  Can I grab it from the DOM or do I have to use some kind of control?

```
<div id="formSpinner">
    <img src="images/spinner.gif" />
    <p>Saving...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding the runat="server" fixed half my issue.  I can now refer to it in my code behind.  However, I can't seem to set the css class or style.  I'm trying to display: block or display: none.

Comment: Jon - edit your question to add the code you're putting in the codebehind and WHERE you're putting it, or consider opening a new question to deal with the further issue. :)

Comment: Sidenote to anyone doing this exact example: check out UpdatePanel's and UpdateProgress controls

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Add the `runat="server"` attribute to it so you have:

```
<div id="formSpinner" runat="server">
    <img src="images/spinner.gif">
    <p>Saving...</p>
</div>
```

That way you can access the class attribute by using:

```
formSpinner.Attributes["class"] = "classOfYourChoice";
```

It's also worth mentioning that the `asp:Panel` control is virtually synonymous (at least as far as rendered markup is concerned) with `div`, so you could also do:

```
<asp:Panel id="formSpinner" runat="server">
    <img src="images/spinner.gif">
    <p>Saving...</p>
</asp:Panel>
```

Which then enables you to write:

```
formSpinner.CssClass = "classOfYourChoice";
```

This gives you more defined access to the property and there are others that may, or may not, be of use to you.

Comment: you can add css like formSpinner.Attributes.add("style","display:none")

Answer (score 13):

Make sure that your div is set to runat="server", then simply reference it in the code-behind and set the "class" attribute.

```
<div runat="server" id="formSpinner">
   ...content...
</div>
```

Code-behind

```
formSpinner.Attributes["class"] = "class-name";
```

Answer (score 6):

This question makes me nervous.  It indicates that maybe you don't understand how using server-side code will impact you're page's DOM state.

Whenever you run server-side code the entire page is rebuilt from scratch.  This has several implications:

- A form is submitted from the client to the web server.  This is about the slowest action that a web browser can take, especially in ASP.Net where the form might be padded with extra fields (ie: ViewState).  Doing it too often for trivial activities will make your app appear to be sluggish, even if everything else is nice and snappy.
- It adds load to your server, in terms of bandwidth (up and down stream) and CPU/memory.  Everything involved in rebuilding your page will have to happen again.  If there are dynamic controls on the page, don't forget to create them.
- **Anything you've done to the DOM since the last request is lost, unless you remember to do it again for this request.**  Your page's DOM is *reset*.

If you can get away with it, you might want to push this down to javascript and avoid the postback.  Perhaps use an XmlHttpRequest() call to trigger any server-side action you need.

Answer (score 3):

Add the runat="server" attribute to the tag, then you can reference it from the codebehind.

Answer (score 3):

Add runat to the element in the markup

```
<div id="formSpinner" runat="server">
    <img src="images/spinner.gif">
    <p>Saving...</p>
</div
```

Then you can get to the control's class attributes by using 
formSpinner.Attributes("class")
It will only be a string, but you should be able to edit it.

Answer (score 3):

How do you do this without runat="server"?  For example, if you have a

```
<body runat="server" id="body1">
```

...and try to update it from within an **Updatepanel** it will never get updated.

However, if you keep it as an ordinary non-server HTML control you can.  Here's the Jquery to update it:

```
$("#body1").addClass('modalBackground');
```

How do you do this in codebehind though?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to make your control runat server in case you need the ID or simply don't want to add it to the viewstate,

```
<div id="formSpinner" class="<%= _css %>">
</div>
```

in the back-end:

```
protected string _css = "modalBackground";
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is conditionally show or hide a <div>, then you could declare it as an <asp:panel > (renders to html as a div tag) and set it's .Visible property.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Peri's post & why we may not want to use viewstate the following code:

`style="<%= _myCSS %>"`
`Protected _myCSS As String = "display: none"`
Is the approach to look at if you're using AJAX, it allows for manipulating the display via asp.net back end code rather than jquery/jscript.