# Setting a class for a DIV that is a server control

Tags: asp.net, css

I different CSS styles, one of which is:

```
#layoutsectiondiv{
    border: 2px dashed #000000; 
   padding: 1px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

I have a aspx page:

```
<div id="testDiv" runat="server">

</div>
```

If it was regular HTML, I would set the style of a div by doing a

```
<div id="layoutsectiondiv">

</div>
```

At runtime (in code behind), I need to dynamically assign different styles to the DIV. How would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the class property and change your css styles to use class selectors instead of id selectors. For example

```
.layoutsectiondiv{}

<div id="testDiv" class="layoutsectiondiv">
</div>
```

## Edit

Make your class only so that you apply it on the specific divs you want. don't reuse your classes. This should be easy since your css is already tied to a specific ID, just put that class on that element.

If you use that class on many types of elements what you suggested would work fine.

Comment: the css ID selector and asp.net doesn't mix very well because .net manages / mangles the ID at runtime.

Comment: If i use a class selector, how do I make sure it can be applied only for this DIV?

I guess I can limit the usage to any DIV by doing a: div.layoutsectiondiv {} correct?

Answer (score 3):

Josh is right, you should use class instead of id.

for your question :

> At runtime (in code behind), I need to
>   dynamically assign different styles to
>   the DIV. How would I do it?

try this :

```
// layoutsectiondiv is defined as class : .layoutsectiondiv{}
testDiv.Attributes["class"] = "layoutsectiondiv";
```

Comment: If i use a class selector, how do I make sure it can be applied only for this DIV? I guess I can limit the usage to any DIV by doing a: div.layoutsectiondiv {} correct?

Comment: yes, div.layoutsectiondiv {} is limits the 'layoutsectiondiv' id used only by divs. But if you want the style applied only the div you want, maybe you should use style attribute ?

Answer (score 3):

So you could use a css id selector this way.

```
#layoutsectiondiv { color: red }
```

with the following html

```
<div id="layoutsectiondiv">    
</div>
```

Or a css class html selector like this.

```
.layoutsectiondiv { color: blue }
```

with the following html

```
<div class="layoutsectiondiv">
</div>
```

If you want to control the style of a particular .net control, ie one that has the runat="server" attribute, then as we know .net will 'mangle' the id to ensure its unique.

In this case in our code we can use FindControl to access the div and change its style

```
<div id="testDiv" runat="server">
</div>
```

ie.

```
        HtmlGenericControl testDiv =
            (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("testDiv");

        // to hide
        testDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");  // OR
        testDiv.Attributes["style"] = "display: none";

        // to show
        testDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display: block"); // OR
        testDiv.Attributes["style"] = "display: block";

        // or to add a class
        testDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "MyCssClassName"); // OR
        testDiv.Attributes["class"] = "MyCssClassName";
```

Here is a good explanation on the difference between css id and class - [CSS: div id VS. div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class).

And here for [How to edit CSS style of a div using C# in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175381/how-to-edit-css-style-of-a-div-using-c-in-net)