# give <a> style in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I had  controls any control have class from style sheet when I click on  event  .I tried to do that but i didnot please any one help me.

aspx:

```
 <a  id="CPCSS" runat="server" href="CompanyProfile.aspx" >Company Profile</a>
```

CEO Word

cs:

```
  protected void CPCSS_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CPCSS.Attributes.Add("Class", "ad_mun_font_r");
    CEOCSS.Attributes.Add("Class", "ad_mun_font");
}
protected void CEOCSS_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CEOCSS.Attributes.Add("Class", "ad_mun_font_r");
    CPCSS.Attributes.Add("Class", "ad_mun_font");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 CPCSS.Attributes.Add("class", "bag_d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

CPCSS.Attributes.Add("class", "bag_d");

Or use HyperLink control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx, property CssClass) instead of raw anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

CPCSS.Attributes["class"] = "bag_d";

This is probably a repeat of

[How to edit CSS style of a div using C# in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175381/how-to-edit-css-style-of-a-div-using-c-in-net)