# change css class in div tag using asp.net(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, css

Hi I want to change a css class properties using c#, like background image, font size, font style, and font. there is a interface for user to change these values. once he save them i add them to db. once user login back i can retrieve them from db but problem is how to show them.

This is the structure of my master page

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <div id="Wrapper" class="abc">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

what is the easy way to change values of abc class according to relevant user?

Comment: "Duplicate" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175381/how-to-edit-css-style-of-a-div-using-c-sharp-in-net

Comment: @RameshRams's example is a good for dynamic css.

Answer (score 4):

try this

client side code

```
 <div id="Wrapper" runat="server" class="abc">
```

Server side code

```
string className="YourClassName";//You can change the name on runtime

Wrapper.Attributes["class"] = className;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `head` inline CSS. The second option is to generate CSS file per user and link it in head.

The first option is much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

first change div to be `runat="server"`

```
 <div id="Wrapper" runat="server" class="abc">
```

and then in code behind you can change class like

```
Wrapper.Attributes["class"]="classname";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an external `CSS` file and write your required values that fetch from `DB` in proper `CSS` style format and link it to your page.

Comment: sounds nice any useful link about writing css file using C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Razor it's pretty neat:

```
<div id="Wrapper" class="@Model.UserSelectedCssClass">
```

This lets you control what goes in the `class` attributes values from your model, assuming your model has a property called `UserSelectedCssClass`.

Comment: The OP asked for MVC ?????

Comment: The OP failed to mention if they were using WebForms or MVC, so since others already answered it for WebForms I provided an answer for MVC as an alternative so all bases were covered.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do two things here.
   
   1) Change div class
   
   2) Add db value in that div

   
First of all change your html to following:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
          <div id="Wrapper" runat="server" class="abc">
           </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
For 1) Wrapper.Attributes["class"] = "Class name";
For 2) Wrapper.InnerHtml = Your DB value.
```

Comment: What you mean by Wrapper.InnerHtml = Your DB value.????? Can you explain it ?

Comment: You said that you retrieve your values from db. If you want to just display those values then Wrapper.InnerHtml = "your values" will display in Wrapper div. If you want to apply your db values style to this div then   Wrapper.Attributes.CssStyle["background"] = "Image from you db"  Wrapper.Attributes.CssStyle["font-size"] = "font size from db" etc. just replace css tag in CssStyle and apply your db values. It will show effect on div("Wrapper") style.

Comment: But the "OP' want to just change the class name only , Not a total div format .

Comment: Deleema Fernando want to change div style according to db values, which are inserted via a form.

Comment: You okay for my side . But where is the OP asked for "Add db value in the div "